# How to maintain same View for different screen resolutions in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I have created a list in my android application, it was looking fine on the default screen i was working on.

But when i switch to `Preview All Screens` Mode..Its starts showing me very different look for each screen, and if i try to change setting for one screens it effects all the screens.

I am unable to understand how to make a universal layout that looks good on all screen sizes.

Given below is the `list item` that i put in my graphical layout, is looking very different in each screen. Same thing happens in every layout.

Kindly guide me how to resolve this problem

Thanks

**XML File**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ep.TransactionHistory" 
     android:background="@drawable/ep"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dip"         
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: don't trust the preview, because it doesn't know your actual list item, it just do some guess work

Comment: You are using android:layout_height="350dp" for ListView. What look are you expect in this case? And you should use match_parent instead of fill_parent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..These settings are working fine on small screens..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html how to do that. check the Header **How to Support Multiple Screens**